# Unable to hide a network site from Communities list

Tags: support, hidden-communities

It seems that I am unable to hide a site under the Stack Exchange network from my list of communities on the profile page:

[image]

When clicking on "Edit list", the site "Android Enthusiasts" is not found in both Visible and Hidden lists.

[image]

Looking at my list of Network accounts on Stack Exchange https://stackexchange.com/users/285492/samuel-liew?tab=accounts, "Android Enthusiasts" is not found as well (I am able to view all other hidden sites).

Comment: Yeah, something appears to be wrong/off with your account on android.SE, since you don't have any activity there can you try to delete the account and re-create it?

Comment: Shouldn't be the case, as I do not have activity on other accounts as well (e.g.: Math.SE). Thought I should report this so that the devs can repro before I attempt to recreate the account.

Comment: Glitches happen all the time, in any software. Stack Exchange is not immune as well. For example, some temporary "database hiccup" when you created the android.SE account might have caused it to not be properly synched with your network profile. It happens, and I'm afraid there's no real fix for this, apart of either re-creating the account or having a developer manually associate the account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After deleting and recreating my account on Android Enthusiasts, the site account is now properly linked to my network account, and I am able to amend the visibility in the Visible Communities list.